# Chrome Frame's notranslate does not work

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, google-translate

I have `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` and `<meta name="google" value="notranslate">` but tries to translate the page.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you have misunderstood the function of the tag.

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

only [prevents google from showing the 'translate this page option' in their search results](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/020684.html), it has no effect on Chrome's translation functionality.

If you [specify the page language correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980520/how-to-specify-your-webpages-language-so-google-chrome-doesnt-offer-to-transla), Chrome won't offer to translate the page for users with the same browser language setting.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Forces the use of the latest IE rendering engine and Chrome Frame (even in an intranet) and has no effect on translation.

Comment: Yes, I want it to prevent Google frame from showing the "translate this page". The language is specified correctly both by header and meta. Yes, I want it to use Google Frame because Trident is crap.

Comment: @george It's the browser, there doesn't appear to be anything you can do to stop it.